# Knitr::Kable in Rmarkdown with Pandoc to word - Prompt of table in word with Rmarkdown

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, kable

I need help to prompt a table in my word document with Rmarkdown (compiled by Pandoc).

I take an exemple to resolve my problem. When I do this command :

````
```{r Table, echo=FALSE}                                                        
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)                             
knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = '100%', dpi=300)                             
knitr::kable(iris)
```
````

I get this :

[image]

But in my word document I wish the table clear...

I tried with DT and WEBSHOT package but it didn't work.

For information, I use the 2.12 version of Pandoc for the compilation.

Thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in my environment with Pandoc 2.19.2 and `knitr` 1.40. You can [*[u]se a Pandoc version not bundled with the RStudio IDE*](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html), as well as upgrade `knitr`, and check whether the problem is resolved.

[image]

If not, the source of your problem comes not from Pandoc or knitr but from other parts. Maybe you need to edit your original post to show a full minimal working example like the following, by adding YAML section.

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE,
  out.width = "100%",
  dpi = 300
)
```

```{r Table, echo=FALSE}                                                        
kable(iris)
```

```{r sessionInfo}
rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
packageVersion("knitr")
```
````